# How to multiple match in Mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having a collection of `Submission` documents.
Every `Submission` has a `bookingId`, a status of the submission and an indicator if an event was sent when the status is `SUCCESS`

I'm trying to create an aggregation which returns a list of unique bookingIds. This list should contain a bookingId if all the submissions for that bookingId have the status `SUCCESS`

Below I'm having a collection of example `Submission` documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7349ebc783305b9331a4b0"),
    "bookingId" : "NW111",
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "sent" : false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7349ebc783305b9331a4b1"),
    "bookingId" : "NW111",
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "sent" : false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7349ebc783305b9331a4b2"),
    "bookingId" : "NW115",
    "status" : "READY",
    "sent" : false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7349ebc783305b9331a4b3"),
    "bookingId" : "NW115",
    "status" : "PROCESSING",
    "sent" : false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7349ebc783305b9331a4b4"),
    "bookingId" : "NW115",
    "status" : "ERROR",
    "sent" : false
}
```

The expected outcome from the example above should be

```
{
    "bookingIds" : ["NW111"]
}
```

What I have so far is the following:

```
db.submissions.aggregate(
    [ { $match : { sent : false } } ]
);
```

Comment: bit confused, what is your expected output?

Comment: @varman, I've added the expected output and a bit more explanation.

Comment: You can also try using: [db.collection.distinct() - Specify Query with Distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/index.html#specify-query-with-distinct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- `$group` by `bookingId` and to set true in `status` when status is SUCCESS otherwise false
- `$match` condition status not equal to false
- `$group` by null and make array of `bookingIds`

```
db.submissions.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$bookingId",
      status: {
        $addToSet: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "SUCCESS"] }, true, false] }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { status: { $ne: false } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      bookingIds: { $push: "$_id" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YZtjQP9KOfE)

---

Second way if you know the list of status then you can try, this way we can exclude `$cond` in first group,

- `$group` by `bookingId` and make unique array of status
- `$match` status not in provided status array
- `$group` by null and make array of `bookingIds`

```
db.submissions.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$bookingId",
      status: { $addToSet: "$status" }
    }
  },
  { $match: { status: { $nin: ["READY", "ERROR", "PROCESSING"] } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      bookingIds: { $push: "$_id" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/luL6dEuYdGx)